# Literal (raw) value as foreign key in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

is it possible to make something like this in sqlite ?

```
FOREIGN KEY(TypeCode, 'ARawValue', IdServeur) REFERENCES OTHERTABLE(TypeCode, TypeElem, IdServeur)
```

it says unknown column "ARawValue" in foreign key definition, is't there another way ?

Comment: Perhaps a better term, and more common than "raw value", is "literal value" or simply a "literal".  I edited the question title to include that term to make it easier for others to find when searching SO.  The term "raw" is often used with string literals to indicate that the string literal will be interpreted exactly without processing escape sequences.  Sometimes such literal values used in defining individual enumeration values are also called "raw" values.

Comment: ok sorry i'm french I don't speak very good english ^^'

Comment: My French is very bad, so no need to apologize. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, this is not possible.  A foreign key constraint must be defined only by columns in the child and parent tables.

Probably the **next best solution is to add a column to the child table with a default value set to the literal value** (and optionally a check constraint that restricts the column to that single value).

---

Strictly speaking, an sqlite *unique partial index* should have been a good alternative solution, but it did not work for me in testing on version 3.28.0.  A [partial index](https://www.sqlite.org/partialindex.html) is an index defined with a WHERE clause and can even be marked as UNIQUE.  The official [foreign key documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) requires a UNIQUE index on the parent table.  There is no explicit exclusion of partial indexes, so I thought it would be a good solution.  I was able to create the index and even define the foreign key constraint on the partial index, but no matter what I tried I got a foreign key error upon INSERT into the child table, even when I had verified that the parent table contained a unique pair of values as defined by the index.

Comment: Ok thanks that's I did the default value column solution, it works well !